# mediaelement.js GUI works great local but not online

Tags: html, mp3, local, mediaelement.js, server

I was looking for a simple mp3 player that **looks the same** in most browsers. I found **mediaelement.js**, I follow all the instructions and works perfect in my local pc, but when I upload all the files to my server I just see the GUI of the browser, not mediaelement.js. 
Why?

[Look the picture of the problem](http://tinetworks.co.uk/2014/img/problem.jpg)

Comment: You should post the problematic code in your question, not put it in a link that may eventually break.

Comment: I found the solution. The code in the official download package is different than the featured in the demo page of mediaelement.js. The code <script></script> too, should be immediately after the <audio></audio> tag.